# Resize triggers with smooth transition

Tags: javascript, css, resize, event-listener

My dashboard has a sidebar that can be hidden/shown with **smooth transition** taking up 0.5s
Unfortunately, this resize triggers '**resize**' event that is changing width of my charts. Problem is, the **width of my inner content wrapper** is acquired instantly when I click, when no resizing happened yet.

[image]
[image]
If I remove smooth transition everything behaves as supposed to, but I kinda want it. Not sure if it could be done using some form of sleep for 0,5s.

```js
static toggleSidebar() {
        const arrow_image_source = document.getElementById("toggleImg").src.toString().split('/').pop();

        // hidden, displaying
        if(arrow_image_source === "sidebar_arrow_right.png"){
            document.getElementById("toggleImg").src="../../assets/img/sidebar_arrow_left.png";
            document.getElementById("sidebarWrapper").style.marginLeft = "0px";
            document.getElementById("pageContentWrapper").style.paddingLeft = "260px";
        }
        // displayed, hiding
        else{
            document.getElementById("toggleImg").src="../../assets/img/sidebar_arrow_right.png";
            document.getElementById("sidebarWrapper").style.marginLeft = "-200px";
            document.getElementById("pageContentWrapper").style.paddingLeft = "60px";
        }
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

/**
 * Calculate & Update state of new dimensions
 */
updateDimensions() {

        const parent = window.document.getElementById('wideChart');
        let update_width  = parent.offsetWidth;
        let update_height = parent.offsetHeight-100 || Math.round(update_width/3);
        this.setState({ width: update_width, height: update_height});

}
```

```css
#pageContentWrapper {
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0 30px 30px calc(var(--sidebar-width) + var(--sidebar-toggler-width) + 30px);
    height: calc(100% - var(--header-height));
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 60px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;

}
```

The important line is

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

that is called after resize to force update on my **eventListener**.

I would be grateful for your thoughts on situation. Some kind of "hack" I thought about is **substracting** the width of the sidebar, since it behaves like an opposite I need, but it does not feel like a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this in a very unclean way that leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

I used **sleep** to wait for transition to resolve. This means **JS will not be usable until transition is over**, but I guess half-second does not give so much space for user to attempt doing anything anyway.

Here is an example:

```js
static async toggleSidebar() {
    const sleepTime = 500;
    const fractions = 10;
    const fraction = sleepTime/fractions;
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        await LeftSidebar.sleep(fraction);
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        }
    }

static sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

The cycle fractions sleep so that it still has the smooth feeling of being a transition-like change on width and height.

Note: I tried using **callback** function to resolve waiting for transition but could not make it work, probably because JS passes transitioning to browser and **continues executing code**, that is why callback executes before transition.